# Is there a way to have navigation for a multipage Data Studio Report at the top of an embedded report?

Tags: navigation, embed, looker-studio, multipage

Typically the embed report only shows multiple pages/index at the bottom of the report if you 
hover over it.

Is there any way to have the navigation and index static at the top of an embedded report?

[Top Navigation Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axako.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in feature but you can create your own navigation bar at the top and set it to appear at report level (for all page).